# UIButton's click action?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am following a book to learn IOs programming. For UIButton, it supposed to have a click action. However I only saw some actions like touch down etc.

Also, want to know why the default action not the "touch down" but "touchUpInside"

I am using XCode 4.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

click action in iOS is represented but `touchUpInside`, since click is a mouse event

touchUpInside, means that the user touched down on a button, and then touch up, while he still is on the same button, which is the normal behavior when you want to tap on a button

Comment: @why not the touch down event?

Comment: touch down equals, mouse event of button down,

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard, you can right click on the `UIButton` and see the list of events available for a UIButton and choose appropriate event based on your requirement.

For a click like action you can use `Touch Up Inside` event.